# What is the default port for an EndpointAddress?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-3.5

I'm debugging Somebody Else's Code... they have created an `EndpointAddress` using the server name, but no port specified, i.e. `http://server/service` or `net.tcp://server/service`.

What port number is it using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For `http`, it is `80`
- For `https`, it is `443`
- For `net.tcp`, it  is `808`

For `http` and `https`, the default port are well-known, and can be searched with little effort. However, for `net.tcp`, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731810.aspx) gives an example of `NetTcpBinding` and then says,

> This example uses **the default TCP port of 808** because the endpoint address URI does not specify a different port number. [...]

Answer (score 0):

For HTTP, it's port 80. For others, it's defined within whatever schema you use (ftp, smtp, gopher, etc).